# insert query mysql and python

Tags: python, mysql

```
def get(infilename):

    fd_in = open(infilename, "r")

    try:
         con = mdb.connect (host=MY_HOST, user=MY_USER, passwd=MY_PASS, db=MY_DB)
         cur = con.cursor()
         insertQuery = "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE" + infilename + "INTO TABLE vlan_area (vlan_id, area)"
```

In python, I want to import a txt file to Mysql database, I want to get the file name dynamically, but this inserQuery is wrong, I don't know how to write it, can anyone help? many thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You forgot the space after `INFILE` and before `INTO`. Also make sure to sanitize `infilename` or risk SQL injections.

Answer (score 1):

should be like this:

```
insertQuery = "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE " + infilename + " INTO TABLE vlan_area 
(vlan_id, area)"
```